# What is the proper way of implementing Orientation switching in iOS

Tags: ios, view, screen-orientation

I am curious about switching orientations in iOS apps.  Every tutorial I've done just talks about having the view auto rotate.  I prefer custom views for landscape and portrait.  I know how to make landscape view controllers and portrait view controllers.  My questions is do you need separate view controllers for handling the different orientations?  If so, do you copy and paste all your code from portrait view controller to landscape view controller and then connect all the outlets and actions on the new view controller?  If this is the case, then is orientation code written in the a separate class (perhaps the app delegate) giving instructions on which view controller to access?  Every time I go looking into this I see code like this written:

```
if (allowLandscape) {
return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation) || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
 }
 else {
 return toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
 }
```

In the above code, what would the toInterfaceOrientation method look like and where is the above code written?  Is it in the view did load method of the portrait / landscape view controllers or in a different class?

Answer (score 0):

If you can avoid duplicating code, that is always the best choice.  (DRY - don't repeat yourself http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)

I would try as much as possible to use one view controller that can handle both layouts.  If the views are really different between portrait and landscape then maybe you just want two view controllers.

I'm not sure about that code you posted.

You should watch this: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=236
They go over the new iOS 6 rotation stuff in depth.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* have separate view controllers for portrait and landscape views, but doing so is not the best solution in most cases. Check out this [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html) for a way to do it.

It would be best to simply rearrange the elements in your subviews and views when switching orientations. Use auto layout to define constraints on your elements. If your interface is fairly complicated, you may have to remove some constraints and add news ones just before the orientation changes. If your interface is very complicated and requires interface elements to completely change their size and position on orientation change, then you will most likely need to removed *all* constraints and then add all new constraints for the new orientation view.  In either case, when adding and removing constraints, do it in the **willRotatetoInterfaceOrientation** view controller method for the best visual effect.

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

    [self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];

    if ((toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) ) {        
        // add landscape constraints here
    }
    else if ((toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)) {
        // add portrait constraints here
    }
}
```

Use the Visual Format Language to programmatically create constraints. One good article I've seen on the VFL is [Visual Format Language](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2013/01/31/visual-format-language-for-autolayout/) by Richard Turton at Command Shift.